# Arrays within variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to produce an array of values to be used by a variable, but I can't get it to work. I don't want to "see" the results. Instead, I want the variable to "use" the results. Here's my code:

```
$rss_results = mysql_query("SELECT feed_id, feed_url, feed_title, feed_order, feed_page_id FROM user_feeds  WHERE ((feed_owner = '" . $_SESSION['UserId'] . "'));");

    if ($rss_results) {

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rss_results))
    {
    $feed->set_feed_url(print "'".$row[feed_url]."',");

    }

    }
    else {
      // something went wrong.
      echo mysql_error();
```

The problem is with the line:

```
$feed->set_feed_url(print "'".$row[feed_url]."',");
```

**EDIT**
1) Yes. I know print doesn't belong there. I forgot to remove it after doing some troubleshooting earlier.

2) I am trying to use this code with an RSS parser calleld SimplePie.

3) Everyone seems to agree that the following code works

```
   $feed->set_feed_url(array("'" . $row['feed_url'] . "',"));
```

...but it doesn't. If I weren't accessing my db, the code would look something like this....

```
$feed->set_feed_url(array('http://www.tmz.com/rss.xml', 'feed://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/topstories.xml'));
```

...which works just fine. I am trying to reproduce that effect using values stored in a mysql db. If the code worked, it would be working. So there must be a problem with the code that is "supposed" to be working.

Comment: It's not helpful to your question, but it should be noted that you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Comment: Why are you setting a method parameter as 'print'? This makes no sense, you pass variables to methods.... not printed characters...

Comment: @DavidBarker - Actually, `print()` always returns 1, so you're not passing printed characters, you're always passing 1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure no one would agree that `$feed->set_feed_url(array("'" . $row['feed_url'] . "',"));` works, because that's not how dynamically populating arrays works.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing an associative array, you must put the index name inside quotes:

Instead of

```
$row[feed_url]
```

use

```
$row['feed_url']
```

Also,

```
$feed->set_feed_url(print "'".$row[feed_url]."',");
```

makes no sense. If you want to pass a value to a method, pass the variable, don't print it to the screen.

```
$feed->set_feed_url("'" . $row['feed_url'] . "',");
```

If you don't want the string you pass to `$feed->set_feed_url()` to be enclosed in `'`s, just pass it like a regular variable:

```
$feed->set_feed_url($row['feed_url']);
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you mention you're trying to pass an array, you have to first initialize it, then populate it, then send it to the method:

```
$urls = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rss_results)) {
    $urls[] = $row['feed_url'];
}
$feed->set_feed_url($urls);
```

Doing this:

```
$feed->set_feed_url(array("'" . $row['feed_url'] . "',"));
```

Will simply pass the following to `$feed->set_feed_url()`:

```
array(
    [0] => String() "'[value of $row['feed_url'] ]',"
)
```

If you want to call `$feed->set_feed_url()` once for each iteration of the loop, this will work fine:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rss_results)) {
    $feed->set_feed_url(array($row['feed_url']));
}
```

**Please note:** You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking :)

Comment: I forgot to remove print from when I was testing something earlier. Also I tried the code you suggested, and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @Richard What does `var_dump($row['feed_url']); exit();` inside the loop produce?

Comment: @Matt cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'http'string(39) "http://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/topstories.xml"

Comment: @Richard I'm assuming you added that AFTER `$feed->set_feed_url()`?

Comment: Yes. I added after $feed->set_feed_url... Also http://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/topstories.xml is only one of the values I am trying to access.

Comment: @Richard Well you're passing the variable to your method correctly. Now the error lies in "why can't cURL resolve the host?" That's a new question.

Comment: @Richard OH OH OH You're passing **'rss.cbc.ca/lineup/topstories.xml'** instead of **rss.cbc.ca/lineup/topstories.xml** See the difference?

Comment: actually CBC government owned radio/tv broadcast in Canada

Comment: @Richard sorry, that was a typo. My point was that you were surrounding your URL with single-quotes.

Comment: The RSS parser I am using requires single quotes. I have updated my original post with more details.

Comment: @Richard, the quotes aren't necessary except to define a `string literal`. I'll update my answer. I didn't realize you needed an `array` to pass to the method.